# no such table: android Sqlite react-native

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

I have created `react-native` project and add component to my project
But if I run code, I have an error:

```
Error handler not provided: ', { message: 'no such table:
```

Where  I am getting wrong?

```
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "IDB_DB_New.sqlite", createFromLocation : 1},this.openCB, this.errorCB);
```

[image]

Same command shows table in DB

[image]